# multiple Select onChange disable submit if no option is selected using jQuery

Tags: jquery, cakephp-2.0

I have **one Multiple Select**.
I want to **disable submit button if no Option selected**.
I want to do this using **jQuery only**.

---

```
<select name="department[]" id="department" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">PHP</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">QA</option>
    <option value="3">JAVA</option>
    <option value="4">iOs</option>
</select>
```

---

Comment: any code to show us ?

Comment: where is your code ?

Comment: $('change',function(){}); event should called when changed and if value is zero then disable submit button. set value zero when no option selected else submit button enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!!

```
$("#department").change(function(){ 
    if($("#department option:selected").text() === '')
    {
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop("disabled",true);
    }
    else
    {
        $('input[type="submit"]').prop("disabled",false);
    }
    });
```

this one works. I was comparing with val() but wasn't working.
  I changed val() with text() because value is in integer.
Thanks [empiric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4202224/empiric) and [user2598136](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2598136/user2598136) for suggestion.